# Is it okay to have 2 strong and 1 good recommendation letters for an MS in Computer Science in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, advisor, recommendation-letter

1 good reco here would mean that it is not a strong one but might talk about my abilities and skills based on a short internship. Is it necessary to have all 3 strong LORs? I might have asked one of my professors for one but I chose to go with my internship advisor (though it may not be a very strong LOR) because it would help the admissions committee understand my acumen outside classroom setting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send in the letters that give the best impression of you, ***based on what is important to the admissions committee***.

For example if you are applying to a thesis based program at a top school and your proposed research area is theoretical and your three strong letters are from well respected academics, I would use those.

If on the other hand you are applying for a non-thesis based more applied program or are applying for an assistantship; your work ethic will be of interest to the committee.  I would use the internship supervisor letter.